# How do I connect to a MySQL database from Clojure?

Tags: mysql, clojure

Assumption: you already have both Clojure and MySQL running on your machine.
How do you make them talk?

Answer (score 29):

Assumption: you already have both Clojure and MySQL running on your machine.

1. checkout and build [clojure-contrib](http://code.google.com/p/clojure-contrib/):

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib.git
   cd clojure-contrib
   build
   ```

   Put the resulting **clojure-contrib.jar** on your **CLASSPATH**.
2. Download [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j.html) and put the **mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar** on your **CLASSPATH**

   *You might have to run your JVM with these arguments:*

   ```
   -Djdbc.drivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   ```
3. Determine the connection URL of your MySQL database

   For example, if you are running MySQL under [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info)  then the URL that you would use in JDBC will look something like:

   ```
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection
           ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/db_name?user=root&password=root")
   ```

   The url is broken down into these components:

   - protocol: `jdbc:`
   - subprotocol: `mysql`
   - db-host: `localhost`
   - db-port: `8889`
   - username
   - password
4. Make this clojure script, modify the database connection parameters to match your URL, save as test.clj, compile and run.

```clj
    (use 'clojure.contrib.sql)               ;;' satisfy prettify

      (let [db-host "localhost"
            db-port 8889
            db-name "db_name"]
        (def db {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               :subprotocol "mysql"
               :subname (str "//" db-host ":" db-port "/" db-name)
               :user "root"
               :password "root"})
        (with-connection db
          (with-query-results rs ["select * from languages"]
            (dorun (map #(println (:language :iso_code %)) rs)))))

            ; rs will be a sequence of maps,
            ; one for each record in the result set.
```

NB This code was adapted from similar code written by Mark Volkmann to [access a Postgres database from Clojure](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/176a11847601cc5a/445026a02e302837)

Comment: The comment (;;' ignore) on the first line is not a required part of the source code - it was added to preserve the syntax colouring of the Clojure source.

Comment: Step 1 is now: git clone git://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib.git

Comment: Notice that you probably won't be able to connect directly to a remote server, so it might be a good idea to port forward some random local port to the server with something like `ssh -L 1234:localhost:3306 user@remoteserver`. Also, check GNU Screen to make it easier to deal with multiple terminals.

Answer (score 15):

This is a lein-friendly answer, with much guidance from [this blog by Nurullah Akkaya](http://nakkaya.com/2009/12/14/using-mysql-with-clojure/):

1. add dependencies to your `project.clj`:

   ```
   (defproject clojql "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
     :description "FIXME: write description"
     :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
                    [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]   ;; for clojure.contrib.sql
                    [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.0.6"]         ;; jdbc 
                    [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.6"]])  ;; mysql driver
   ```
2. run `lein deps` from the command line to grab the dependencies
3. specify your connection information in a map:

   ```
   user=> (use 'clojure.contrib.sql)
   nil
   user=> (def db {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
                   :subprotocol "mysql" 
                   :subname "//localhost:3306/nmr" 
                   :user "root"})
   ```
4. use `with-connection` and `with-query-results` macros [(& others)](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/sql-api.html#clojure.contrib.sql):

   ```
   user=> (with-connection db (with-query-results rs ["select * from sometable"] (count rs)))
   667
   ```

*steps 3 & 4 can either be from the repl (`lein repl` to start it) or within normal source code*

Comment: Thanks! By the way, the latest "stable" versions at this time are 1.4.0 for clojure, 0.2.3 for java.jdbc, and 5.1.22 for mysql-connector-java. clojure-contrib is no longer needed and clojure.contrib.sql is now part of java.jdbc. See https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc for an example.

Answer (score 9):

As of 2016:

using [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/),
add dependencies inside project.clj:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
               [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.4.2"]
               [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.38"]]
```

require database connector inside namespace definition:

```
(ns name.space
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as j]))
```

define database connection:

```
(def db-map {:subprotocol "mysql"
             :subname "//localhost:3306/SCHEME"
             :user "DB_USER"
             :password "DB_USER_PASS"})
```

query the database:

```
(j/query db-map ["SELECT * FROM table"])
```

find more examples at
http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want some syntactic sugar, you can try Korma.

[Docs](http://sqlkorma.com/)

[Github](https://github.com/korma/Korma)

```
(use 'korma.db)
(defdb db (postgres {:db "mydb"
                     :user "user"
                     :password "dbpass"}))

(use 'korma.core)
(defentity users)


(select users)
;; executes: SELECT * FROM users


(select users
  (where (or (= :usersname "chris")
             (= :email "chris@chris.com"))))
;; executes: SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.usersname = 'chris' OR users.email = 'chris@chris.com')
```

Comment: That's not really mysql though.

Comment: @Ven, While the `defdb` in the snippet above indeed points to Postgres, the documentation covers MySql amongst other databases. See here: http://sqlkorma.com/docs#db
Maybe the code snippet can be updated to have a better correlation with the question.