# Clojure MySQL Syntax Error Exception ("[...] near '????????????????' [...]")

Tags: mysql, exception, jdbc, clojure

I'm having trouble doing anything with clojure.contrib.sql beyond establishing a connection.

I have a mysqld running on localhost:3306 with a database called `clj_db`.
The user 'clj_user'@'localhost' with password 'clj_pass' can access this database.

When trying to "select * from clj_table" I get a "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1".

What am I doing wrong?

**`clj_db`.`clj_table`**

```
CREATE TABLE `clj_table` (
  `col_one` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col_two` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**mysql_test.clj**

```
(ns test.mysql
    (:use clojure.contrib.sql)
)

(def db-settings
    {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    :subprotocol "mysql"
    :subname "//localhost:3306/clj_db"
    :user "clj_user"
    :password "clj_pass"})

(with-connection db-settings
    (with-query-results rs ["select * from clj_table"]
        (dorun (map #(println (:col_one :col_two %)) rs))
    ))
```

**Output**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1 (mysql_test.clj:0)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:4658)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:4972)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:4939)
   at clojure.main$load_script__7405.invoke(main.clj:213)
   at clojure.main$script_opt__7442.invoke(main.clj:265)
   at clojure.main$main__7466.doInvoke(main.clj:346)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:441)
   at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:367)
   at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:179)
   at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:476)
   at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1048)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3563)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3495)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2687)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1859)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3593)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2199)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:784)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:350)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
   at clojure.contrib.sql.internal$get_connection__218.invoke(internal.clj:85)
   at clojure.contrib.sql.internal$with_connection_STAR___226.invoke(internal.clj:102)
   at test.mysql$eval__386.invoke(mysql_test.clj:12)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:4642)
   ...10 more
```

Comment: Additional Information:
clojure-1.1.0 ---
clojure-contrib-1.1.0 ---
mysql-connector-java-5.1.11-bin ---
java 1.5.0 ---
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've switched to Sun's JDK6 instead of GIJ.

I got "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure". 
I found [this thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,297075,297075#msg-297075), which really helped me a lot.

I've added the option "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" and it now works fine.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem only I was using Java. I found [this](http://www.vanheusden.com/java/tt.php) post and the solution described there worked for me.

The trick was to add "useJvmCharsetConverters=true" to the end of the connection-string.

Answer (score 0):

the code looks very similar to the (presumably working) code in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613929/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-from-clojure)
perhaps its a problem with the version of clojure-contrib.

when I macroexpand the code from these two question they come out the same so it seems likely that the problem is not with the contents of mysql_test.clj.

Comment: Yup, I had a look at that, too.

Just to be sure I've downloaded clojure and clojure-contrib releases again, but I get the same output.