# Getting connection error when i connect database

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stumped SQL Exception for JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742927/stumped-sql-exception-for-jdbc)

I am using Linux server. But when i establish connection in mysql server i am  getting this type of exception.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??????????????' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1027)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3361)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3295)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1852)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2470)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1669)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3336)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1979)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:287)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
at testthread.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:28)
at testthread.ConnectionFactory.main(ConnectionFactory.java:39)
```

Comment: please post code, this is a SQL syntax error which immediately looks like a failure to substitute bindings - but without code hard to tell

Comment: All those question marks makes we wonder if you have a String encoding issue

Comment: No - the error isn't at the connect phase - it's in the query being submitted. Please show us the query.

Comment: This looks a lot like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2166216/1343161).

Comment: This is the query which im using

 server = "";
            databasename = "";
            user = "";
            password = "";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + "/" + databasename+"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println(con);;
            return con;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("***************connection failed********************");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with either your Java version or your character set configuration as explained in: [Stumped SQL Exception for JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742927/stumped-sql-exception-for-jdbc)

Comment: I am passing all this parameters but . I am not post this things.
this code running fine in my local but when i run this code in linux server it's showing connection error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your url to `"jdbc:mysql//" + user + "@" + password + ":" + server + "/" + databasename`?